# In SBT, how does one `addCompilerPlugin` from Git?

Tags: sbt

Normally, when not using Git, you can just write:

```
addCompilerPlugin("something" % "blah" ...)

scalacOptions += "-P:blah:..."
```

This `addCompilerPlugin` takes a `ModuleID`. But here... I've tried adding:

```
lazy val root = project in file(".") dependsOn
  uri("git://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover.git#master")
```

to the `project/plugins.sbt` as well as:

```
lazy val wartRemover = RootProject(
  uri("git://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover.git#master"))

lazy val root = Project(...).settings(
  ...
  scalacOptions += "-P:wartremover:...",
  ...
  ) depends on wartRemover
```

Both result in:

```
[error] (root/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
  org.brianmckenna#wartremover_2.10.3;0.5-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** The project `wartremover` has not been published for Scala version `2.10.3`. Downgrade yours with the following in `build.sbt` among the other necessary settings:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
```

### Detailed procedure focusing on Scala 2.10.3

The following in `build.sbt`

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.brianmckenna" % "wartremover" % "0.5" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

adds `org.brianmckenna:wartremover:0.5:plugin->default(compile)` to `libraryDependencies`.

```
[sbt-0-13-2]> show libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, org.brianmckenna:wartremover:0.5:plugin->default(compile))
```

So to use a `RootProject` that points at the project `wartremover` at GitHub I had to use the following in `build.sbt` (this is the complete file):

```
scalacOptions in root += "-P:wartremover:traverser:org.brianmckenna.wartremover.warts.Unsafe"

lazy val root = project in file(".") dependsOn wartRemover % "plugin->default(compile)"

lazy val wartRemover = RootProject(
  uri("git://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover.git#master"))
```

Since the project `wartremover` is not published for `2.10.3` I followed the steps below:

1. Show available `projects`

   ```
   [root]> projects
   [info] In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.2/
   [info]   * root
   [info] In git://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover.git#master
   [info]     wartremover
   ```
2. Switch to `wartremover` and `publishLocal` it for `scalaVersion` set to `2.10.3`.

   ```
   [wartremover]> set scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
   [info] Defining wartremover/*:scalaVersion
   [info] The new value will be used by wartremover/*:allDependencies, wartremover/*:assemblyPackageScala::assemblyDefaultJarName and 12 others.
   [info]  Run `last` for details.
   [info] Reapplying settings...
   [info] Set current project to wartremover (in build git://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover.git#master)

   [wartremover]> publishLocal
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/staging/d6dd3d2e3d818e69943a/wartremover/target/scala-2.10/wartremover_2.10.3-0.6-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
   [info] Updating {git://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover.git#master}wartremover...
   ...
   [info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org.brianmckenna/wartremover_2.10.3/0.6-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
   [success] Total time: 7 s, completed Jan 18, 2014 11:34:07 PM
   ```
3. Switch to the project `root` and do `update`. It should now work fine.

   ```
   [wartremover]> project {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.2/}
   [info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.2/)
   [root]> update
   [info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.2/}root...
   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
   [info] Done updating.
   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 18, 2014 11:36:24 PM
   ```
4. `console` should work fine now, too.

   ```
   [root]> console
   [info] Starting scala interpreter...
   [info]
   <console>:5: error: var is disabled
     var value: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain = _
         ^
   Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_45).
   Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
   Type :help for more information.

   scala>
   ```

   The error message worries me, though. I don't know the plugin and neither do I know how to get rid of it. It also happens when I follow the steps described in [Compiler plugin](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover#compiler-plugin) when `scalaVersion := "2.10.2"` is set in `build.sbt` (so the compiler plugin's available in the repo).

Comment: `dependsOn wartRemover % "plugin->default(compile)"` is exactly what I was after in this question, thank you! <3 The remaining issue is, as you say, 2.10.2 vs 2.10.3. Local publishing is not feasible, since I'd like it to work for other devs out-of-the-box. Since it's not published for 2.10.3, I ended up publishing it myself -> https://maven.michalrus.com/org/brianmckenna/ . I wonder if there's a way to change `scalaVersion` in a subproject downloaded from Git, because that is the only change I needed to make. The plugin is 2.10.3 ready.

Comment: Glad I could help. I missed that part with `scalaVersion` as `scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.3"` should work fine. Could you confirm so I can add it to Item 2.